# Get variable from POST?

Tags: php, variables, post

Form:

```
<form name="edit" method="post" action="add_comment">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="8" id="editor_table"><tbody>
...
<?php echo $_REQUEST[$saveStatus]; ?> /
<?php echo $_POST[$saveStatus]; ?>   /
<?php echo $saveStatus; ?>          / Mine unsuccefull try's
...
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

POST Action:

```
if ($username != null && $content != null) {
    ...

    $saveStatus = '<span id="saveStatus" class="upload_success">сохранен</span>';

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
} else 
if ($username == null || $content == null || $username == null && $content == null) {
    $saveStatus = '<span id="saveStatus" class="upload_error">ошибка при сохранении</span>';

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");
    exit;
}
```

I'm trying to submit form, and then it going to refer me back to form page with dynamic $saveStatus variable, but no luck.

Comment: you should be getting many undefined error notices and you shouldn't rely on `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

Comment: where are you setting `$saveStatus`?

Comment: Request knows nothing about previous requests unless you use sessions. That's why setting `$saveStatus` and then changing location does nothing.

Comment: @Machavity In POST action.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But I don't see any of these.

Comment: adding `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1);` at the top of all your php didn't produce anything? viewing HTML source also for all files. The other variables' values and assignments are unknown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh, now I see `Notice: Undefined variable: saveStatus in E:\OpenServer\domains\eks.ru\edit.php on line 102

Notice: Undefined index: in E:\OpenServer\domains\eks.ru\edit.php on line 102`

Comment: you will need to use either `isset()` or `!empty()` or a ternary operator in order to stop getting those error messages and making sure they all contain value. I think you should be able to find out why your code failed now :-)